# How to return other view in an action method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to return the view of Index action method in create action method.I tried writing `return View("Index");` in Index action method but nothing happened.Both my action methods are in the same controller. How can I do that?

Code:

```
public class GuestbookController : Controller
{        
    // GET: /Guestbook/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GuestbookContext"].ToString());
        string query = string.Format("Select * from Guestbook");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<GuestbookEntry> li = new List<GuestbookEntry>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            GuestbookEntry GuestbookEntry = new GuestbookEntry();
            GuestbookEntry.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
            GuestbookEntry.Message = Convert.ToString(reader["Message"]);
            GuestbookEntry.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"]);
            GuestbookEntry.DateAdded = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateAdded"]);
            li.Add(GuestbookEntry);    
        }
        conn.Close();
        var mostRecentEntries =(from entry in li orderby entry.DateAdded descending select entry);
        ViewBag.Entries = mostRecentEntries.ToList();
        return View(); 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(GuestbookEntry entry) 
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GuestbookContext"].ToString());
        string query = string.Format("Insert into [Guestbook] values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", entry.Name, entry.Message, DateTime.Now);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        return View("Index"); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `nothing happened`? I think you need `return RedirectToAction("Index")`

Answer (score 2):

You are only using the view, and not the action, so the ViewBag you are filling, wont be available.

You can use use [`RedirectToAction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to redirect the current action to the other action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(GuestbookEntry entry) 
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GuestbookContext"].ToString());
    string query = string.Format("Insert into [Guestbook] values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", entry.Name, entry.Message, DateTime.Now);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to return to the index page as if it was called from the client then you should use:

```
return Index(); //If you don't care about adjusting URL on client's machine
```

Or

```
RedirectToAction("Index") //If you want to update client's URL
```

Please note that the second option does entail a full round trip to the client and back to the server and can not be used easily in case of Ajax calls, while the first option "stays on the server" and can be used with Ajax.